# Converting an array to JSON and getting incorrect format

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy

```
import json
import numpy as np


class NpEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
hotelListDivided = np.array_split(arr, 2)

json_str = json.dumps(arr[i], cls=NpEncoder)
```

The above code is from [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-object-of-type-ndarray-is-not-json-serializable#:~:text=The%20Python%20%22TypeError%3A%20Object%20of,before%20serializing%20it%20to%20JSON.](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-object-of-type-ndarray-is-not-json-serializable#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20%22TypeError%3A%20Object%20of,before%20serializing%20it%20to%20JSON.))

I have split up `arr` into multiple arrays using `np.array_split(arr, len(objectListLength))` and then putting it into a for loop (that I took out for here as it's too much code) hence the `[i]`

The problem is when I am using it like this in the http body request it sends it like this `'hotels': {'hotel': '["662091", "889933"]'}}` when for the request to be successful it needs to be sent like this `'hotels': {'hotel': ['662091', '889933']}}`

As you can see it has both an extra single quote before and after the square brackets and double quotes which should be single quotes. How do I parse this correctly to JSON?

Answer (score -1):

Ended up splitting the array a different way which fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).